# Redeclaration of const javascript with aJax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to load page just changing the .loadPage html element using jQuery. I call a new page using the function **loadPage(page)** and this load the page using aJax. In my loadPage function has this:

```
$.ajax(`assets/views/${page}.html`)
    .done(html => {
        $('.loadPage').html(html);
    })
    .fail(() => {
        global.loadPage('error');
    });
```

But when I try to call the below page, this returns to me on console:  *SyntaxError: redeclaration of const perfil*

**perfil.html page**

```
<script src="assets/js/ctrl/perfil.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

**perfil.js archive**

```
const perfil = {
    load(){
        //more code here
    }
    //more code here...
}
```

When I use the *var* type, this error isn't showed, but I don't want to use var.

What does mean? I have to use the var type? 
Note: When I tried to use *let* the same error occurred.

Comment: Yes. If something *is* variable theres no sense of using *const*. Alternatively you could `Object.freeze` to have a constant behaviour

Comment: So I can't use const to create this object?, so I have to use the var or simply don't use anyone?

Comment: well the main problem is loading the same code twice. But if you write a clientside project, you should keep in mind that global scope is used by everyone, so you should be careful when declaring variables in it

Comment: Or maybe you do not include all the resources when you load the page this way....

Comment: Ok Jonas, thank you so much!

Comment: @epascarello but if I don't put this some of my functions will not work. How I can do it better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check if perfil does exist already, like this:

```
window.perfil = window.perfil || {
  load(){ /*...*/ }
};
```

Or you somehow load it only once.

Comment: Thanks, this work for me. Is the window the global scope?

Comment: @victor kind of.

Answer (score 0):

The same variable name occurs as a function parameter and is then redeclared using a let/var assignment in a function body again. Redeclaring the same variable within the same function or block scope using let/var is not allowed in JavaScript. So what you can do is if the variable is not present then only you have to create that variable.

like below..

```js
if (!perfil){
// do something
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. On console: `ReferenceError: perfil is not defined`